# Getting Toast Message from Notification

Tags: android

Is it possible to have a Toast being shown when I click on one of the Variants of Notification? I tried to sending this Toast by intent to another class but could not find a way to do so. 
Also, i have tried just creating intent to another class which just has a function of creating a Toast message upon being called, but this did not work because the Toast was being shown upon creation of Notification. Please help. Thanks.

```
    Intent intent = new Intent();

    PendingIntent pendingIntent = PendingIntent.getActivity(this, 0, intent, PendingIntent.FLAG_CANCEL_CURRENT);

    NotificationCompat.Builder builder = new NotificationCompat.Builder(this);

    builder.setTicker("Info")
            .setContentTitle("Info ")
            .setContentText("NotiText")
            .addAction(R.drawable.ic_stat_name, "This should make Toast upon clicking", pendingIntentCall)
.setSmallIcon(R.drawable.ic_stat_name).setAutoCancel(true);
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your `intent` does nothing. When passing the Intent to PendingActivity.getActivity(...), you must define it as an explicit intent for an Activity. For example:

```
Intent intent = new Intent(this, SomeActivity.class);
```

But if you only want to show a toast message, it would be probably better not to start an activity, because that would be quite an expensive operation for that purpose. Instead, you can create a PendingIntent also for a service or a broadcast. For example:

```
Intent intent = new Intent(this, MyBroadcastReceiver.class);
PendingIntent pendingIntent = PendingIntent.getBroadcast(this, 0, intent, PendingIntent.FLAG_CANCEL_CURRENT);
```

And `MyBroadcastReceiver.java` could look like this (basically):

```
public class MyBroadcastReceiver extends BroadcastReceiver {

    @Override
    public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {
        Toast.makeText(context.getApplicationContext(), "Your message", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
    }
}
```

Btw, it is recommended to add an action or extra to the intent when you create it, and check for that action or extra when receiving the intent to verify that it's actually the intent that you expected to receive.

Comment: Yeah, that did actually work. Actually, the mistake here is kinda stupid because i used .getActivity instead of .getBroadcast on pending. Thanks for great answer!